# Java.lang.NumberFormatException Error

Tags: java, serial-port

I am having this error:

The output shows 3 C's which are from the program. I typed in "12.34" myself.

The anticipated output was supposed to be:

```
C
C
C
12.34
12.34 is the first string
12.34 is the second string
```

12.34 was supposed to be converted to double but I got weird characters instead.

[image]

I was not able to find the solution. I tried different methods but I still got the same error.

Here is my program:

```
    int ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    double[] conArray = new double[3];
    //string[] conArray = new string[3];
    double dataDbl;
    String dataStr = null;
    double data = 0;
    String s = "C";
    String t = "Hello";
    //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    //String con = "C";
    ////System.out.println("Starting!");
    System.out.println("C");
    buffer.setLength(0);
    System.out.println("C");
    buffer.setLength(0);
    System.out.println("C");

    buffer.delete(0,buffer.length());


    while (i < 300) {
        ch = inStream.read();
        if ((ch == '\r') || (ch == '\n')) {
            i = 300;
        }
        buffer.append((char)ch);
        i++;
    }
    dataStr = buffer.toString();
    dataDbl = Double.parseDouble(dataStr.trim());

    conArray[counter] = dataDbl;

    outStream.writeChars(dataStr);
    System.out.println(" is the first string"); 

    outStream.writeDouble(conArray[counter]);
    System.out.println(" is the first data");  

    buffer.delete(0,buffer.length());
    counter++;
```

I found the fix, here it is:

```
                int trash = 0;
                trash = inStream.read();
                System.out.println("C");
                while (true) {
                    ch2 = inStream.read();
                    if ((ch2 == '\r') || (ch2 == '\n')) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (ch2 != 32) {
                       sb.append((char)ch2);
                    }
```

I put an integer called trash to get rid of the spaces or unwanted characters before inStream. Worked perfectly. The problem was the serial device terminates its output with  and . These two stays in the buffer unread so when the next data is read, nothing really is there and thus error occurs at Double.parseDouble(dataStr.trim());.

Comment: Any idea why the error occurred?

Comment: Agree with @juergend, besides, this code doesn't compile, where are you defining buffer?

Comment: How to accept? I know this sounds so dumb...

Comment: Just click on the big, green check mark you have in the left of the best answer, but you should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first...

Comment: Okay, i'll review all my threads.

Comment: @jmort253 Sorry I didn't know that before. I thought: vote up = accept.

Comment: @JpehNoynay - Nope, upvotes award 10 reputation points, and anyone with 15 reputation can upvote. Accepts award 15 reputation, and only the question-asker can award these by clicking on the checkbox beside the most correct/helpful answer. Thank you for taking care of that!

Comment: @EugenioCuevas, I tried declaring the buffer in my program. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Print the String you are trying to parse as double to the console, just before parsing it:

```
System.out.println(dataStr.trim());
```

It should show a parseable double (in your case 12.34) otherwise you are doing something wrong getting it from the stream

Comment: I tried it and it appeared as it should be (12.34).

Comment: ...but does not appear through outStream

Comment: What kind of object is outStream? And where are you expecting it to appear, console?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with outStream. I'll get back to you when I fix it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to exit a loop is to use `break;` In your case you are making sure the loop will exit but you will still be adding `\r` or `\n` to the buffer which is not part of a number.

Stepping through a debugger is the quickest way to find out what the code is doing, esp when its not doing what you expect.  In an IDE it is usually the button next to Run.

Comment: Can I run a debugger with a modem? I'm uploading the program into it.

Comment: I would get the program working locally first, emulating any devices/services which you don't have.